# Cross-referencing different files with a global counter

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a collection of about one hundred of short `tex` documents (1 or 2 pages each). I would like to reference them, not by their name, but by a number. This number is to be defined by the order of compilation.

**Minimal example**: Say one of my documents explains Lie groups, and another document talks about my grandfather's life who, let's pretend, invented Lie groups. I'd like to refer each document to the other, using the file name, and not the number which is arbitrary.

So if run *first* `pdflatex lie_group.tex` and *then* `pdflatex grandfather.tex`, I'd like to have `lie_groups.pdf`:

[image]

and `grandfather.pdf`:

[image]

On the reverse, if I compile `grandfather.tex` first, the output should be:

[image]

and

[image]

The question is how to define `\magicFileNumber` and `\magicReference` to produce the above-described outcome (coloring set aside) in the following way:

```
% this is lie_groups.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Lie groups} (\textit{This is Document~\magicFileNumber}) 
Lie groups were introduced by my grandfather whose life is described in Document~\magicReference{grandfather}.
\end{document}
```

and

```
% this is grandfather.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\textbf{My grandfather} (\textit{This is Document~\magicFileNumber}) 
He invented Lie groups, see Document~\magicReference{lie_groups}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) in your file `file1.tex` type `\makeatletter
\expandafter\@gobblefour\jobname
\makeatother` 2) i can't  see the point `\ref{file1}-->1`?  why don't just type 1?

Comment: @touhami Because the file names I have given here are just dummy names. It could be 'history_Japan' and 'Lie_groups' instead of file1 and file2. Also, I don't want to change all the refs if I change the order of compilation. I'll check your answer a bit later.

Comment: But this is even easier,   i  will update my  answer.

Comment: now it's clear, `\magicFileNumber` go from 1 to `?`  you said that you have  `about one hundred`?

Comment: @touhami Yes, actually between one and two hundreds but I don't think that makes a difference. Of course each document only makes reference to a few others, if any.

Comment: you  need to compile all files first, so do you want to use a script?

Comment: @touhami. Yes, in practice I'll write the file names in a txt file, and loop over each file to compile it. The first run should generate a global number for each file, and the second run should replace the "??" with the right counter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. We need to creat a file  `files.tex`

**files.tex** (files by order  of compilation)

---

```
\newcounter{mtfile}
\refstepcounter{mtfile}
\label{liegroups}
\refstepcounter{mtfile}
\label{grandfather}
\refstepcounter{mtfile}
\label{otherfile}
```

---

**Or**

```
\newcounter{mtfile}

\newcommand*{\runpdflatex}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{mtfile}\label{#1}}

\runpdflatex{liegroups}
\runpdflatex{grandfather}
\runpdflatex{otherfile}
```

---

and input it in each file.

**grandfather.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{files.tex}

\begin{document}
\textbf{My grandfather} (\textit{This is Document~\ref{grandfather}}) 
He invented Lie groups, see Document~\ref{liegroups}.
\end{document}
```

**Note that we don't  need to copile all files.**

Comment: So simple, and it works with any label (does not have to be the file name) and directory organisation. Labels should however not include underscore.

Comment: yes i forgot  to note this.